# How to validate The current time is within the specified time period?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, php-carbon

I have 2 times in table

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-14 16:56:0 | 2020-12-16 03:02:00 |

I use Carbon to  check current time is within the start and end times? But it not work.

Error: Expected null, string, DateTime or DateTimeInterface

```
$current = new Carbon();
$start = khuyenmai::select('ngaybd')->where('id_sp',1)->first();
$end = khuyenmai::select('ngaykt')->where('id_sp',1)->first();
var_dump($current->between($start,  $end));
```

how to check current date is between two dates above and get boolean values true or false?

Comment: You got a pretty clear error message, so – go check if the variables you are using, actually contain what you think they should (a.k.a. most basic debugging), and see if their types are compatible with what the documentation says.

Comment: Return the object `$start->ngaybd, $end->ngaykt`

Answer (score 0):

You can check this by next simple query:

```
select 'true' from tbl where now() between start_date and end_date and id = 1;
```

or Laravel style:

```
$test = khuyenmai::select('ngaykt')
    ->where('id_sp',1)
    ->whereRaw('now() between start_date and end_date')
    ->first();
```